# Matching multiple words in mysql query using "LIKE"

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

My application allows searching of articles. So when a user enters the string "articlex" the query works & results are show but when multiple words are entered "articlex articley" the query shows no results.

Cuurently I'm using this query

```
$querySub = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE (col1 LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%") OR (col2 LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%") OR (col3 LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%")';
```

Where `$search_string` only contains the input by user

How can I make the query applicable for multiple words as well?

Comment: You'd better use **prepared statement** on `PDO`. Your current code allows **SQL injection** attack.

Comment: If i use mysql_real_esacep_string(), would that secure it?

Comment: Yes, but `mysql_**` functions are **deprecated**. See here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php You can choose `Mysqli` or `PDO`. I recommend you `PDO`.

Answer (score 2):

Example for `PDO`

```
/* Assume $pdo is already prepared as PDO instance. */

// search query split by spaces
$user_input = 'foo bar baz';

// create string for PDO::prepare()
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE ';
$wheres = $values = array();
foreach (array_filter(explode(' ', $user_input), 'strlen') as $keyword) {
    $wheres[] = 'col1 LIKE ?';
    $values[] = '%' . addcslashes($keyword, '%_\\') . '%'; // this is escape for LIKE search
}
$sql .= $wheres ? implode(' OR ', $wheres) : '1';

// bind values and execute
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($values);
```

Example for `mysql_**` functions **(deprecated)**

```
/* Assume $link is already prepared as MySQL resource. */

// search query split by spaces
$user_input = 'foo bar baz';

// create string for mysql_auery()
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE ';
foreach (array_filter(explode(' ', $user_input), 'strlen') as $keyword) {
    $wheres[] = 'col1 LIKE ' . mysql_real_escape_string(
        '%' . addcslashes($keyword, '%_\\') . '%',
        $link
    );
}
$sql .= !empty($wheres) ? implode(' OR ', $wheres) : '1';

// execute
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

While using variables for like query, you could use

> Select * from table where keyword LIKE '%{$to_be_searched}%'

Answer (score -1):

You can use REGEXP for this perpose .....or if you want multiple word search then you need to explode search string by space and then search this string from table using LIKE

```
       if you search "articlex articley" then it will search whole word in LIKE operator
```

Answer (score -1):

use only one "%" at the end. like

```
$querySub = SELECT * FROM table WHERE (col1 LIKE '$search_string%'");
```

This will search for both "articlex" and "articley"

Answer (score -1):

1: This will be return **should**  record

> select * from products  where title like "%word1%" or
> title LIKE "word2";

**note: if you have so many word then use dynamic query generator which generate title like "%word3%" or title like"**%word4%" or ........

2: This will be return **must**  records

> select * from products  where title like "%word1%word2%word3%";